# Is it possible to get the information when file was opened, along with the opening user account?

Tags: linux, files, permissions

I want to know when and by whom a file was read. I used `ls -ul` command for the last accessed date, but that does not show *who* accessed it.

Could you please help out?

Kr, Mahesh

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have some sort of auditing enabled before the fact to gather solid information like that. If that is not already in place when the access takes place, then the information you seek is likely already lost.

That said, you might be able to infer who accessed the file based on who was logged into the system at the time of access. You can usually get that information via `last`. How accurate your inference will be is going to be depend on the number of users who were on. If you have access to their shell command history you may find evidence there to strengthen your case. However, this can be easily manipulated and/or obfuscated, so a lack of evidence should not be considered an exoneration.

Another avenue to explore might be that if they used an escalation mechanism, such as `sudo` or `su` in order to view the file, then you may find evidence in the relevant logging location. Whether this logging exists, and where it can be found, will depend on your distro and your system setup.